# How can I restore my VM?

Tags: virtualbox

I was trying to resize my disk (without success) and I had to remove my disk. After I added back my disk, when I start my VM I get a black screen. I get the Ubuntu loading screen then it goes black. How can I solve this problem? Or how can I get the data on my VM back? I am using VirtualBox.
Those are the general settings:

[image: img1]

Those are the storage settings:

[image: img2]

EDIT: it is possible that it's not running because there is no space left on the disk. How can I free some space? The only thing I have on it are just a couple c scripts which don't use too much memory. That's why want to recover my vm.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: ubuntu version 20.04.1 LTS